# Spring Security Anonymous User

Tags: authentication, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am Using **Grails 2.2.3** with **spring security plugin 1.2.7.3** dependency.
when I check **springSecurity.isLoggedIn()** the result is false but the user is authenticated.
spring recognizes my user as anonymous User. **is it just about Using HTTP and HTTPS** ?
Because it works fine on my local machine and the problem occurs when I deploy my app on tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was about that the client could not get a JsessionId and that was because of one my filters securing the session.
so When you have no jsesionid no matter what you would be recognized as anonymous user by the Spring Security.
Also it could be disabled in spring config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use isAnonymous() to check for anonymous user

Comment: I think `isLoggedIn` uses `isAnonymous` at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/4d917ed848d16b457d89a62dca7e8cce2289a84b/grails-app/services/grails/plugins/springsecurity/SpringSecurityService.groovy#L94-L97.

Comment: good point. That is the way it works in 1.x. I would say check the config at this point.

Comment: I checked it before and it was true so i was looking for the problem